# Exception in main class java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: java, mysql, exception

I am getting the following error when i execute the java program

```
 Exception in main class java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

**Program:**

```
    String query = "select id from testtable where status=\"" + 1 + "\" limit 10";
                    PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet res = s.executeQuery();

                   while (res.next()) {

                        CId = res.getString(1);
                        System.out.println("cid:"+CId);

               String delquery = "delete from testtable2 where comid=\"" + CId + "\"";
                    PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement(delquery);
                    System.out.println("del:"+pre.executeUpdate());

            String delquery2 = "delete from testtable where id=\"" + CId + "\"";
                    PreparedStatement pre2 = conn.prepareStatement(delquery2);
                    pre2.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Are you running these queries inside a transaction?

Comment: No am not using any transaction

Comment: Seems the table are locked.

Comment: @Sudhanshu : How can we check that my table got locked or not